# how to stop postfix relay server to forward bounce/NDR emails to client

Tags: postfix, email-bounces, ndr

I have a setup with 1 pure mail server, lets call it *mail*, and 1 web server, lets call it *web*.

When *web* sends out email to an external server it uses *mail* as relay. Both servers use postfix. *mail* has a MX record and is the the official mail server for the domain, *web* has no MX record and on this server postfix works basically as a mail client only.

The problem: When *web* sends email via *mail*, and that email is rejected by the remote mail server, it gets bounced back to *mail* which forwards the NDR to *web*. What I'd like to have is that *mail* accepts and stores the bounce emails.

What postfix options do I need on both servers to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Because all of our emails contain an *envelope from* address of *bounce@ourdomain.net* I was able to add a transport rule on *mail* server that enforces local delivery.

In *main.cf* I have this line:

```
transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/transport.regexp
```

In */etc/postfix/transport.regexp* this line redirects all email send to *bounce@ourdomain.net* to the virtual process for local delivery:

```
/^bounce@ourdomain\.net$/                        virtual:
```

If you don't have a multi domain setup like we do, instead of *virtual* you could probably use *local* or *lmtp*